# Iterate through JSON in python and filter values based on key to get desired result

Tags: python, arrays, json

I am trying to loop through JSON and filter value based on the specific key ( config_name). Tried to create a dictionary, but I couldn't get it working so far.

```
    [
{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCINoOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:31", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}},
{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCIOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:30", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}}
]
```

My intention is to retrieve values(failedtests,partialpassedtests) baased on each config_name.

tried using the below code and iterating over it without any success.

```
 with open(test_logs) as json_file:
       data = json.load(json_file)
```

Not well equipped with python, first day for me

Comment: please provide sample output.

Comment: I will just save values in individual variables and pass to different methods. so for first row it will be , nightlyCIOcean , failedtests number, etc saved and passed to another method

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit to get you started.

```py
import json

SOURCE_DATA = '''
 [
{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCINoOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:31", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}},
{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCIOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:30", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}}
]
'''

my_data = json.loads(SOURCE_DATA)

for config in my_data:
    summary = config['summary']
    print(summary['configName'], summary['failedTests'], summary['passedTests'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, but you can run the following code:

```
myList= [{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCINoOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:31", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}},{"summary": {"configName": "nightlyCIOcean", "dateTimeOfFormatting": "2019-12-06 12:20:30", "failedTests": 0, "partialPassedTests": 1, "passedTests": 0, "totalTests": 1}}]



for a in myList:
    print(a.get("summary").get("configName"))
```

With this code you get the value of "configName"